# How do I export a Jena SDB model from the command line?

Tags: rdf, jena, semantic-web, triplestore, turtle-rdf

I've got a moderately sized (25 million or so triples) Jena SDB database that I'd like to export to an N3 formatted file.  How might I approach this?

I've tried using the `sdbdump` tool that's included with Jena, but all that comes out of the DB is prefixes.  Here's the connection info from my `sdb.ttl` file:

```
<#conn> rdf:type sdb:SDBConnection ;     
    sdb:sdbType       "mysql" ;
    sdb:sdbHost       "localhost" ;
    sdb:sdbName       "dbname" ;
    sdb:engine        "InnoDB" ;
```

Here's the command I'm invoking:

```
./bin/sdbdump --out=N3
```

As far as I can tell, `$SDBROOT` is set up properly, and `sdbdump` doesn't complain about it being incorrect.

What am I missing?  Is this the right approach to creating a N3 file from a moderately sized MySQL-backed Jena SDB database?

Comment: TTL = Turtle format, not N3. The formats are highly alike, but not 100% the same.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra, you're exactly right.  I had tried a couple of different formats and copied the wrong command.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your database contains named graphs and has nothing in the default graph.

Since Turtle is a triples only format `sdbdump` would only output triples in the default graph when invoked

If you want to dump named graphs then you likely need to use a format that supports named graphs e.g.

```
./bin/sdbdump --out=NQUADS
```

Comment: I tried doing an NQUADS dump, but got a `NoWriterForLangException`.  JSONLD did work, and I know it supports named graphs, but I did not get any data back.